# Image segmentation python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want to ask for some advice about the procedure that I should implement for image segmentation working with opencv in python.

I have this kind of image [image]and my purpose is to detect the white fiber like here [image: image2]

Does anyone have a proposition of the steps of image processing that I should do?

Comment: _I have this kind of image._ How many images do you process? Do **ALL** images exactly look like the presented? When they vary, **HOW** do they vary? May the lighting or the position of the object change? May the white fibre look different along several images? You might get a perfect solution for this specific image, but which fail for the next image. So, please provide more details, and more sample images, to might get ideas for a robust processing. Which ideas did **YOU** have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can notice that object's color is different than the background, I found [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/) helpful. The concept is the following :
1.apply RGB filters to your image,
2.grab contours using OpenCV, then
3.apply some handcraft conditions to them so as to fit your desired output, and finally
4.produce the box.

If all of your images share the same color patterns, this should work.. If not, it will prove noisy ..